# Problem in starting the PDF from the first page

Tags: classicthesis

I am writing a document, which has several chapters, using the classicthesis package, which can be downloaded [in this link](https://code.google.com/p/classicthesis/downloads/list).

I compile the `.tex` file and create the PDF. When I use Adobe Reader to open the PDF, the starting page is not the first page and Adobe Reader shows the 7th page. Is there a way to specify that the starting page is the first page of the document?

Comment: I don't use adobe reader.check with [free sumatra pdf viewer](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) if you are on windows.

Comment: More information is needed.  This sounds like a `\frontmatter` vs `\mainmatter` issue to me, but my crystal ball is notoriously unreliable.

Comment: @texenthusiast: I have to be able to start the PDF document correctly on all PDF viewers including Adobe Reader.

Comment: Yes, my idea was to diagnose the error source, is it from `.tex` side then [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) may be needed @jon says  or pdf viewer side

Comment: @texenthusiast: The link I provided in the question contains an example. Would that work?

Comment: kindly take us virtually to the procedure adopted for generating `.pdf` from `.tex` by taking your link doc to make [simple example](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl). As i am not aware of it.

Comment: Set hyperref at pdfstartpage=1

Comment: At least in the `classicthesis-config.tex` file on CTAN, there is pdfstartpage=3 setting for hyperref.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what is your problem. The .pdf file provided with the package is flawless. If you really want a solution from us, please provide us a minimal working example. I want to help you, but I am not sure how I can do it.

Comment: Thanks to @Yiannis and @Jan. I set the `pdfstartpage=1` in `classicthesis-config.tex` and the generated PDF starts from the very first page.

Comment: @Ahmad Glad you had the issue solved. Won't you post an answer and accept it so that the question doesn't show up in the unanswered section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially, the setting for `hyperref` in the file `classicthesis-config.tex` is `pdfstartpage=3`. Therefore, modifying it to `pdfstartpage=1` sets the starting page of the document to the first page.

Comment: this problem happens sometimes when I use pgf-umlcd package.